# Create a new polygon layer containing the extent of a layer

Tags: qgis, polygon, layers, extents

I am trying to create a difference layer from an overlay layer and a base layer. The base layer (colored orange in the image below) has a larger extent than the overlay layer (light brown) when zoomed out, but I want it to have the same extent with the overlay layer:

[image: polygon extent]

I could manually create a new base layer by drawing a rectangle or square over the overlay layer, but I prefer the exact extent of the overlay layer.

How can I create a new layer containing a polygon that shows the extent of the overlay layer?

Answer (score 1):

You should find what you want there :

```
Processing toolbox / QGIS geoalgorithms / Vector general tools / Polygon from layer extent
```

Comment: The toolbox name has changed to `Create layer from extent` for QGIS 3.6 and ahead